# How to avoid accelerating over typeliness with large C# Tuples?

Tags: c#, class, tuples, instance

---

### Motivation

I ‗occasionally‗, despite their inadequacies, find C# `Tuple`s useful.

Of these times, there have been reasons for dabbling in large `Tuple`s over more initially obvious approaches such as creating a specific class or struct or a general, for example tree like class.

They include being able to define `Tuple`s in more places/scopes. Usually in more local and/or temporary scopes such as inside functions right where needed and invisible elsewhere, or as return types, even in array definitions. `Tuple`s are also in some respects less bulky than normal classes and those with (instantiated?) nested classes. Sometimes, although often a weakness, even the data structure like feel of a `Tuple`s members being automatically named `Item1` `Item2` etc... can be preferable.

---

### Issue

Or more an issue of elegance, see 'motivation' above.

See this pseudo C# code:

```
var t = new Tuple<
    Tuple<float, float>,
    Tuple<
        Tuple<box, box, UInt16>,
        Tuple<float, float, float, float>>>
    ((1.5, 1.5), (
        (new box(2, 2), new box(3, 2), 4),
        (1.5, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8)));
```

---

But as shown in the actual code below, the type name repetition required increases super-linearly to the number of nodes/members.

```
var t = new Tuple<
    Tuple<float, float>,
    Tuple<
        Tuple<Box, Box, UInt16>,
        Tuple<float, float, float, float>>>
    (new Tuple<float, float>(1.5, 1.5),
    new Tuple<Tuple<box, box, UInt16>, Tuple<float, float, float, float>>(
        new Tuple<box, box, UInt16>(new box(2, 2), new box(3, 2), 4),
        new Tuple<float, float, float, float>(1.5, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8)));
```

---

```
nodes: 14
that are leaves: 8
types stated in first example: 14

types stated in the C-Sharp code: 38
    If all leaves were classes, like `box`: 45
    In a 31 node, 16 leaf, binary tree: 113
```

It'll get worse still with more size, so far being 3.6x, imagine this line of code:

```
byte byte byte byt count = 4;
```

---

### ‗Question‗

Is there a way to avoid this repetition of the specification of types?

Comment: I can't see a question...

Comment: Put it in a class instead.

Comment: With `Tuple`, you hide a lot of the meaning. Say this is `Tuple<int, int>` and one represents the width/height. It would be hard to know which is which.

Comment: Use Tuple.Create static method to get generic types inference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to avoid having to retype the type name so many times, you can use [`Tuple.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var t = 
    Tuple.Create(
        Tuple.Create(1.5, 1.5),
        Tuple.Create(
            Tuple.Create(new box(2, 2), new box(3, 2), (ushort)4),
            Tuple.Create(1.5, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8)));
```

Note that the this will use type inference where possible, so if you need to generate a `Tuple` that uses a type that cannot be directly inferred from the parameter (such as a base type or a `ushort` in the case of the `4` literal), you have to do some deliberate casting or explicitly specify the types in that call to `Tuple.Create`.

Still, there are times where you *have* to spell out the entire type name, for example, in type members or method signatures. In this case, you can use an often overlooked feature of C#, the [type alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx):

```
using MyTuple = Tuple<Tuple<float, float>, Tuple<Tuple<box, box, UInt16>, Tuple<float, float, float, float>>>;
...

public class MyClass 
{
    public MyTuple MyFunc(MyTuple foo, MyTuple bar) { ... }
}
```

The signature of the method shown above would be *absolutely horrendous* without the alias. And of course, you're free to mix and match aliases, too, meaning that complex generic class names can be broken down into simpler and simpler forms until they become more manageable.

However, I would still generally recommend using properly designed classes where possible.

Answer (score 1):

The souls of a thousand **classes are** screaming, trying to get out and manifest themselves. Yet you have crushed them to submission, and **the** meaningful names they once had are now lost. Your code pines for simplicity and sensibility, but no **answer** is to be found.

Comment: Only a few bits of my code pine in this way, OFC I usually use Classes, I've tidied the question to better show this. Classes do have their limitations, C# needs the same thing that happened to C++ lately with the update, except it didn't work well enough with C++, it's still not as good as C# :)

Comment: @alan2here "C# needs the same thing that happened to C++ lately with the update" what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: C++11, with the new features.